# How to combine multiple sass directories into one css file?

Tags: css, sass

I've got two scss directories that I need to compile into one css output file. So of course, compiling one directory into a css output file is:

```
sass --watch scss/template.scss:css/template.css
```

How can I combine two directories into the same css output file? Using some type of concatenation? Something like

```
sass --watch scss/template.scss + scss/override.scss:css/template.css
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an index.scss file which imports both template.scss and override.scss, and then watch with `sass --watch index.scss:css/template.css`

index.scss

```
@import 'scss/template';
@import 'scss/override';
```

Edit: Here's the documentation for the sass import functionality:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import